# How to pushViewController from a custom UIView in Swift?

Tags: swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a custom UIView and it will show when user go to specific UIViewController, on this UIView there is a button.

When user click on the button, I want to push a viewcontroller but I cannot call `self.navigationController?.pushViewController(inputCode, animated: true)`

How can I do the same behavior from a custom UIView? And also I am not using storyboard.

Comment: Yes ... You need to use `delegate` or `closure` for that

Answer (score 0):

You can't access UIViewController from a custom UIView unless you pass its reference. Anyways, it wouldn't be nice if you do so. You can handle it by adding action from the UIViewController side

```
yourCustomView.yourActionButton.addTaget(self, action: #selector(self.tappedYourActionButton), forControlEvents: .touchUpInside)

@objc func tappedYourActionButton(_ sender: UIButton?) {

}
```